# SPLIT RANGE ON A TABLE

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, table

I'm trying to create a job that executed automatically the rotation of partitions on a table.

I executed the next script but the ranges are not rotating successfully

```
DECLARE @PARTITION_FUNCATION_NAME VARCHAR(50) = 'pfPerformanceSummary';

DECLARE @NewBounderyDay DATETIME,
        @MinBounderyDay DATETIME,
        @PartitionFunctionId BIGINT,
        @PartitionIdToDelete INT,
        @FileGroupName VARCHAR(50);

SELECT @PartitionFunctionId = function_id 
FROM sys.partition_functions
WHERE [name] = @PARTITION_FUNCATION_NAME;

SELECT 
    @MinBounderyDay = CONVERT(DATETIME,MIN([value])), 
    @NewBounderyDay = DATEADD(HOUR,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,MAX([value]))),
    @PartitionIdToDelete = MIN(boundary_id)
FROM sys.partition_range_values pr
LEFT JOIN sys.partition_functions pf ON pf.function_id = pr.function_id 
WHERE pr.function_id = @PartitionFunctionId
AND boundary_id>1;

TRUNCATE TABLE PerformanceSummary WITH (PARTITIONS (@PartitionIdToDelete));

ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfPerformanceSummary() MERGE RANGE (@MinBounderyDay);

ALTER PARTITION SCHEME psPerformanceSummary NEXT USED [PRIMARY];

ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfPerformanceSummary() SPLIT RANGE (@NewBounderyDay);
```

Before executed the script the table looks
[image]

But after executed looks
[image]

Can you help about what is wrong in the sentence, please?

Comment: `AND boundary_id>1` why is that there, given that it's a `RIGHT` range? Don't you want to merge the lowest partition rather than second lowest? Side note: The `LEFT JOIN` seems extraneous.